# Install ie9 under wine?

Tags: wine

Before anyone asks, Im a web developer so I need it, not because I want to use it.

So, I am trying to install ie9 in wine (I can get it to run under virtualbox but it is slow/laggy/cumbersome).

But when I try to run the installer I get "Internet Explorer 9 Can Only Be Installed Under Windows Vista Or Windows 7".

So is there any way to change what os wine reports itself as?

Comment: Try setting Wine to run as Windows 7 (run `winecfg` and change the "windows version" to Windows 7 instead of Windows XP). it might work.

Comment: Have you tried virtualbox with the vhd microsoft especially created for testing IE9?